# Feature engineering of X,Y coordinates in neighborhoods of San Francisco

Tags: r, prediction

I am participating in a starter Kaggle competition(Crimes in San Francisco) in which I want to predict the category of a crime using a bunch of predictor variables including X and Y coordinates of a crime. As I doubt of the predictive power of the coordinates, I want to transform these variables to something more relevant to the crime category.

So I am thinking that if I had the neighbourhood of San Francisco in which the crime took place, it would be more informative than the actual coordinates of the crime. I can find the neighbourhoods online but of course I cant use the borders of each neighbour to classify the corresponding crime because their shapes are not rectangular or anything like that.

Does anyone have any idea about how I could solve this one?

Thanks guys

---

Well that's interesting AntoniosK and it's getting close to what I want to accomplish. The problem is that the information " south-east and 2km from city center" can lead to more than one neighborhoods. [image]
I am still thinking that the partition of the city in neighborhoods is valuable because the socio-economic and structural differences between them ( there is a reason why the neighborhoods of each city are separated as such, right?) can lead to a higher probability for a certain category crime and a lower one for another.

That said, your idea made me thinking of using the south-east etc mapping and then use the angle of the segment(point to city center) with x axis to map the point to appropriate neighborhood. I am on it right now. Thanks

Comment: Might be useful to transform them to something that shows you the geographical location in a different form. First, you need a (manual?) process that maps a set of coordinates to one of the 4 (main regions) south-west, south-east, north-west, north-east. Then create the distance between a set of coordinates and the city centre, or any other place you think might be more useful. So, in the end for each set of coordinates you'll have info like : south-east and 2km from city centre to help you classify/predict the crime type.

Comment: @AntoniosK i've edited the question to answer your comment so I could attach a photo and make my point more clear.

Comment: I agree that the angle is one more piece of knowledge that will give you a more presice location info. Because indeed south-east and 2km from centre will give you an area and that area is part of a circle circumference and will get bigger as the radius gets bigger. However, don't "underestimate" the coordinants themselves. Might have more predictive power than you think. Try to check first if they are useful as they are.

Comment: I am kind of afraid to try all of the ideas that pop up about predictors engineering because i am using bayesian categorical logistic  regression method and that's a computationally difficult technique. Coupled with the volume of the data, each try will ( a rough calculation) need 2 days. Though I came to realize that you may have a point defending the power of coordinates. After all, it may be more important to know if the crime was located on a big highway instead of a dark alley than to know the exact neighbour in order to predict the category of a crime.  I will give it a shot. Thanks dude

Comment: Yes, probably speed is another thing you need to consider. Is it possible to start investigating the predictive power of coordinates in a much smaller sample of data (random or stratified; your choice)? Any chance you can use another method for feature selection (i.e. simpler/faster method to pick the top N most important variables) and then use those in your Bayesian model? Not sure if you like that method/philosophy, but just mentioning it as an idea.

Comment: I don't think I can submit a subset of the dataset to Kaggle and if I dont, I can't estimate the predictive power of the explanatories . As for the other part, now that i come to think of it I could use both coordinates and neighborhoods( when I get them ready). I won't even bother with variable selection since I will give the coefficients of the regression a multivariate normal prior so their collinearities will be embedded in the variance/precision matrix.  Remind me of referring your name in my thesis, haha .

Comment: Of course you won't submit that sample. You'll just use it as an extra process/exercise to see which variables are more important/powerful. Then you use those on the full dataset. Will just save you time from using full dataset on various ideas you have.

Answer (score 0):

After some time on the problem I found that the procedure I want to perform is titled " reverse geocoding". It also turns out that there are some api's to solve this. The best according to my opinion is revgeocode() function contained in ggmap package(google's edition). This one though has a query limit per day(2500 queries) unless you pay for extra.

The one that I turned to though is geonames package and GNneighbourhood function that turns coordinates to neighbours. It is free, though I have experienced some errors(keep in mind that this one is only for US and Canada cities)

[revgeocode function-ggmap package](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggmap/docs/revgeocode)

[Gnneighbourhood-geonames package](http://www.inside-r.org/node/343633)

Comment: Both links above return a 404

Comment: Yeah, some years have passed since this post. However i am pretty sure if you google the reverse geocoding process, you will find libraries that support it, ggmap or beyond.